# Getting import error when using gensim.summeraization

Tags: python-2.7, gensim

I am trying to use gensim's summarizer and keywords to extract important keywords and summarizing contents. However, I am getting the following error:

```
from gensim.summarization import summarize
```

Traceback:

```
 ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-70743b938b65> in <module>()
----> 1 from gensim.summarization import summarize

ImportError: No module named summarization
```

I checked the version which is gensim 0.10.0. I am using Anaconda distribution and installed gensim using

```
conda install gensim
```

Any help would greatly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please update gensim to the latest version.

```
pip/conda install --upgrade gensim
```